# Editing my own answer duplicates it. Bug?

Tags: bug, multiple-answers

*Previously on [meta.ELU](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10746/bug-editing-my-own-answer-duplicates-it)...*

I answered a question on ELU, but forgot to add a link to a reference, so I edited it to add it. I'm not too sure what happened, but it seems to have duplicated the answer, one with the 'correct' one, and the other with no links (there was one before) and no content in the blockquotes (although they are still blockquote blocks)

[Here's the question I'm talking about](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408628/adjective-that-means-control-freak/).

Is this a bug, or due to a break in connection with my phone and so not really worth worrying about? I have no idea how to reproduce it...

It's slightly different to [this SO bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280179/6083675) because we don't have stack snippets on ELU.

For purposes of working out what has happened, I'm using a phone browser (BlackBerry, don't ask why :P) on the website (mobile version) with WiFi but it's pretty knackered sometimes so I might have blipped connection when it was POSTing to the SE servers.

---

Here's some screenshots:

[image: No quotes or links..]

[image: Codez lookin' empty]

Comment: Why didn't you delete the old answer that you don't want anymore?

Comment: @Servy so people with sub 10k rep could see what I was on about...

Comment: Well, we can't really fix it. The only people who can fix the bug are SE developers, and they can see deleted posts anywhere. Screenshot with what you have there now should be enough for us "mortals".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but maybe other users have had similar experiences?

Comment: @Mari-LouA screenshot is enough, we don't have tools to debug this and those are two totally separate answers. (I did check their timelines, nothing weird there.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Someone else can still share their similar experience even if you've deleted your duplicate answer.

Comment: @Servy it's not my answer. But seeing two identical answers makes it easier to understand, the screenshot idea is a good one tho'.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd argh! why can't you add images on the mobile site? The 'add image box is halfway off my screen in 'full site' mode...

Comment: @Mari-LouA et. al., all done...

Comment: Yeah mobile web is still quite limited. Hopefully with the apps development dead, they will give some love to mobile web soon.

Comment: I usually find face the similar bug while using mobile chat i.e an edit to chat message sometimes duplicates the message and I use to delete older one.